# Dependent intellij modules with different versions of external dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, multi-project

I am creating a library, a new feature in Spring 4 allows the user of the library some neat benefits. However, I also want to support spring 3.

I am having some difficulties when setting this up correctly in Intellij using gradle.

I created two gradle sub projects `mylib` and `mylib-spring3`. I let `mylib` be dependent on `spring 4` while `mylib-spring3` is dependent on `spring 3`. Since `mylib-spring3` is just some helper classes for `spring 3` it must also depend on `mylib`. In other words:

mylib/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.5.RELEASE'
}
```

mylib-spring3/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.13.RELEASE'
    compile(project(':mylib')) { transitive = false }
}
```

This works in gradle, but it does not work when imported to Intellij because Intellij exports `mylib`'s `spring 4` dependency. The button for disabling the export is only for compile-time. I still get `spring 4` on `mylib-spring3`'s runtime classpath.

Any suggestions on how to structure this would be greatly appreciated.